# Python getpass function

Tags: python, getpass

I have tried to use this getpass function in python to type in my password, but when I run the code, i cannot input anything in the terminal.

Thanks in advance! :D

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEarZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8Yha.png)

Answer (score 0):

from the getpass-docs:

> If you call getpass from within IDLE, the input may be done in the terminal you launched IDLE from rather than the idle window itself.

try running the .py file inside a terminal window, cmd/bash/powershell!